# usbc extension cable pinout

Tags: usb

Does anyone know where I could find the pinout for a USB Type C male to USB Type C female cable? I have found several "extension" cables on amazon such as this one :

[https://www.amazon.com/Faracent-Extension-Charging-Nintendo-Touchbar/dp/B071DMMW4J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071DMMW4J)

But I have been unsuccessful in finding any sort of datasheet that explains their pinout. The reason I am asking is because I am working on a project that would require me to go from USB 2.0 to 3.2 and I am curious to see as to how their backwards compatibility works.

Comment: What exactly is the point in USB 2.0 to USB 3.2? I mean, you have a terrible bottleneck. USB 2.0 has only 2 data lines (while 3.2 has many-many). Also, search in the internet for "usb type c pinout" and open images. Do you mean you want to switch physical rectangular port on one side to oval on the other?

Comment: A cable like that will only be used to extend another USB-C cable. I'd expect it to be wired straight through on all pins.

Comment: @Finbarr, I would rather think that this kind of product would have an active circuitry and a full-scale power CC and delivery controller.